# Histogram Gnuplot mixing Clustered/Stacked

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I have a histogram consisiting in 6 columns. I would like to clustered them in pairs to have two clustered group made of two stacked colums. I almost done it, except that the legend is has double the entries that I want and that the graph is not centered

```
set terminal epslatex standalone color size 4.0in,3.0in background rgb "white"
set output 'massFlowSection.tex'

set xtics("ex1" 1, "ex2" 2, "ex3" 3)
#set yrange [0:100]

set style fill solid border -1
#set key invert
#set grid

num_of_ksptypes=2
set boxwidth 0.5/num_of_ksptypes
dx=0.5/num_of_ksptypes
offset=-0.12

plot 'data1.dat' using ($1+offset):($2+$3+$4) title "par3"  with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset):($3+$4) title "par2" with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset):($4) title "par1" with boxes, \
         'data2.dat' using ($1+offset+dx):($2+$3+$4) title "par3"  with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset+dx):($2+$3) title "par2" with boxes, \
         ''                   using ($1+offset+dx):($4)  title "par1" with boxes
```

The entry data are file data1.dat

```
area  par3     par2    par1  
1     0.0078   0.0211  0     
2     0.0139   0.0302  0    
3     0.0169   0       0.119
```

and file data2.dat

```
nr  par3     par2    par1 
1   0.0083   0.0233  0     
2   0.0151   0.0302  0    
3   0.0173   0       0.211
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: `to clustered them in pairs to have two clustered group made of two stacked colums` - I don't understand that. Can you draw for example how should it look like? Or find an example online how it should look like? For the data provided, at best?

Comment: Excuse me, probably I was not really clear because I don't knwo realle well the therminology since I'm exploring for the first time histogram with gnuplot. I upload an example

Comment: how is the underlying data for your second example organized? It doesn't look like it's the data you show above.

Comment: Exactly, that's an example I found by googling.

Comment: well, in order to help we need to know what your input is and what the desired output is. Currently, you provided some data with wrong output and a desired output without corresponding data. How should we be able to help with this?

Comment: I update the question since I made some progress

Comment: No idea? @theozh

Comment: of course some ideas, but no time, at least not yet ;-). One more question: You said you don't want double entries in the legend. How do you want to handle the colors for both groups? 1. identical, 2. completely different, or 3. maybe slightly brighter for the first group, and slightly darker for the second group?

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I would like to specify the colo by my own as rgb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might be a starting point for further tweaking.
I tried to keep it general, such that you can easily add more columns or rows.

In your code you are summing up the column values "manually" `$2+$3+$4`. There are certainly ways to sum up columns "automatically".
But, I allowed myself to transpose your data, because I found it easier. Let me know if you can live with it. Since gnuplot has no transpose function, you either have to implement it yourself or use external software. The latter, I usually try to avoid because of platform-independence. I guess there is also a way to do the same plot for your original data.

I prefer the plotting style `with boxxyerror` instead of `with boxes` which is always starting from zero. 
Actually, the last plot command is plotting nothing but just getting somehow the legend. This is still suboptimal. A additional declaration could be added which tells you which stack is Data1 and which is Data2.

**Code:**

```
### Histogram stacked and grouped
reset session

$Data1 <<EOD
area  "ex 1"  "ex 2"  "ex 3"
par1  0       0       0.119
par2  0.0211  0.0302  0
par3  0.0078  0.0139  0.0169
EOD

$Data2 <<EOD
nr    "ex 1"  "ex 2"  "ex 3"
par1  0       0       0.211
par2  0.0233  0.0302  0
par3  0.0083  0.0151  0.0173
EOD

set key top left
set style fill solid border -1

Cols = 3
Groups = 2
GroupGap = 0.2
BoxScale = 0.9
BoxWidth = (1.0-GroupGap)/Groups
Offset(g,i) = i-1.5+GroupGap/2.0 + BoxWidth/2 +(g-1)*BoxWidth

myXtic(i) = columnhead(i)
BoxL(g,i) = Offset(g,i)-BoxWidth/2.*BoxScale
BoxR(g,i) = Offset(g,i)+BoxWidth/2.*BoxScale
set xrange [0.5:Cols+0.5]

array myPalette[6] = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0xffaaaa, 0xaaffaa, 0xaaaaff]
myColors(n) = myPalette[n+1+(g-1)*3]

set table $Legend
    plot $Data1 u (strcol(1)) w table
unset table

plot \
    for [i=2:Cols+1] $Data1 u (g=1,i-1):(int($0)?sum:sum=0):\
      (BoxL(g,i)):(BoxR(g,i)):(sum):(sum=sum+column(i)):(myColors($0)) \
      skip 1 w boxxy lc rgb var not, \
    for [i=2:Cols+1] $Data2 u (g=2,i-1):(int($0)?sum:sum=0):\
      (BoxL(g,i)):(BoxR(g,i)):(sum):(sum=sum+column(i)):(myColors($0)) \
      skip 1 w boxxy lc rgb var not, \
    for [i=2:|$Legend|] $Data1 u (g=1,i-1):(NaN):(myColors(i-2)): \
      xtic(columnhead(i)) w boxes lc rgb var ti word($Legend[i],1)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]